# convert a flat array that has a "path" property to a nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, tree, nested

I have a flat array like this example :

```
[
  {
    'name':'itemA',
    'path':'foo/bar'
  },
  {
    'name':'itemB',
    'path':'bar/foo'
  },
  {
    'name':'itemC',
    'path':'foo'
  },
  {
    'name':'itemD',
    'path':'bar'
  },
  {
    'name':'itemE',
    'path':'foo/bar/wizz'
  },
  {
    'name':'itemF',
    'path':'bar/foo'
  },
]
```

I want to build a tree based on the "path" property, so I could get this output :

```
[
  {
    'name':'itemD',
    'path':'bar',
    'items':[
      {
        'name':'itemD',
        'path':'bar/foo'
      },
      {
        'name':'itemF',
        'path':'bar/foo'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    'name':'itemC',
    'path':'foo',
    'items':[
      {
        'name':'itemA',
        'path':'foo/bar',
        'items':
        [
          {
            'name':'itemE',
            'path':'foo/bar/wizz'
          }
        ]
      },
    ]
  }
]
```

How could I achieve that ?
I found out some examples like [this one](https://jsfiddle.net/alexandrupausan/qjxpLhfu/), but they are based on a parent ID and not a "path" like mine.

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

You could find the level or add a new object for the level of the splitted path.

```js
const
    data = [{ name: 'itemA', path: 'foo/bar' }, { name: 'itemB', path: 'bar/foo' }, { name: 'itemC', path: 'foo' }, { name: 'itemD', path: 'bar' }, { name: 'itemE', path: 'foo/bar/wizz' }, { name: 'itemF', path: 'bar/foo' }],
    tree = data.reduce((items, { name, path }) => {
        path.split('/').reduce((o, _, i, p) => {
            let path = p.slice(0, i + 1).join('/'),
                temp = (o.items ??= []).find(q => q.path === path);

            if (!temp) o.items.push(temp = { name, path });
            return temp;
        }, { items });
        return items;
    }, []);
   
console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I, thanks, it helped ! I almost got it. Would you mind have a look here ? I'm stuck trying to improve your function... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65909368/how-to-improve-this-function-that-converts-a-flat-array-into-a-tree